# how to trigger input onchange from Angular spec

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-test

I have an `input` `HTML` `File` filed

```
<input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="question-file-upload" formControlName="image" (change)="handleFileSelect($event)">
```

I want to unit test `handleFileSelect` function. But I don't know how to trigger the `onChange` method of the input. Following is the `spec` I have written but I get error `imageInputNE.onchange is not a function`

```
fit('should keep track of image counter when an image is loaded', () => {
    let newPracticeQuestionComponent = component;
    expect(newPracticeQuestionComponent.currentImageAttachmentCount).toBe(0);
    let imageInputDE = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css("#question-file-upload"));
    expect(imageInputDE).toBeTruthy();
    spyOn(newPracticeQuestionComponent,'handleFileSelect');

    let imageInputNE:HTMLElement = imageInputDE.nativeElement as HTMLElement;
    imageInputNE.onchange(new Event("some event"));
    expect(newPracticeQuestionComponent.handleFileSelect).toHaveBeenCalled();


  });
```

Answer (score 4):

Referring to documentation at Mozilla's website,  Events are usually triggered by "external" sources like Buttons, they can also be triggered programmatically, such as by calling the HTMLElement.click() method of an element. or by defining the event, then sending it to a specified target using EventTarget.dispatchEvent().

I suppose that `click` is a simple Event and can be triggered programatically but `change` Event for `<input type=file..>` is more complicated as it requires selecting a file, converting into a blog, updating `files` property etc. So probably for this reason, I cannot just simply call `imageElementNE.change()`.

So I thought of using `dispatchEvent` and it seem to work

1) I created an Event explicitly. I suppose `Event`'s constructor takes 2 arguments, 2nd is optional.

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Event

```
event = new Event(typeArg, eventInit);
```

From documentation, `typeArg` is a DOMString representing the name of the event. In other words, the 1st argument seem to be the `type` of the event. As I want to send `change` event, I need to call it `change`.

For the `eventInit` part, I looked at the definition of `change` event at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change and picked the values of `bubbles` and `cancelable` from there

```
let fileSelectEvent = new Event("change",{bubbles:true,
    cancelable: false});
```

This creates an `Event` which looks as follows (I must confess I don't understand much of it)

```
 Event {isTrusted: false, type: "change", target: input#question-file-upload.custom-file-input.ng-untouched.ng-pristine.ng-valid, currentTarget: input#question-file-upload.custom-file-input.ng-untouched.ng-pristine.ng-valid, eventPhase: 2, …}bubbles: truecancelBubble: falsecancelable: falsecomposed: falsecurrentTarget: nulldefaultPrevented: falseeventPhase: 0isTrusted: falsepath: (10) [input#question-file-upload.custom-file-input.ng-untouched.ng-pristine.ng-valid, div#file-upload.custom-file, div.form-group, form#new-question-form.practice-question-form.ng-untouched.ng-pristine.ng-invalid, div#form-div.body__div--background, div#root0, body, html, document, Window]returnValue: truesrcElement: input#question-file-upload.custom-file-input.ng-untouched.ng-pristine.ng-validtarget: input#question-file-upload.custom-file-input.ng-untouched.ng-pristine.ng-validtimeStamp: 3759.4000000026426type: "change"__proto__: Event
```

2) Once the `Event` was created, I called the `dispatchEvent` method on `imageInputNE`. Comparing with `EventTarget.dispatchEvent()`, I think it means that the `EventTarget` is triggering the event (in my case `imageInputNE` is triggering `fileSelectEvent`.

```
imageInputNE.dispatchEvent(fileSelectEvent);
```

The entire spec which passed is

```
  fit('should keep track of image counter when an image is loaded', () => {
    let newPracticeQuestionComponent = component;
    expect(newPracticeQuestionComponent.currentImageAttachmentCount).toBe(0);
    let imageInputDE = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css("#question-file-upload"));
    expect(imageInputDE).toBeTruthy();
    spyOn(newPracticeQuestionComponent,'handleFileSelect');/*.and.callThrough();/*.and.callFake((event)=>{
      console.log("fake handleFileSelect called with event",event);
    });*/
    /*
    nativeElemenet hasn'nt got any type. As this program will run in a browser, we can
    typecast it to HTMLElement so that we can access prperties and methods of the
    corresponding nativeElement

     The HTMLElement interface represents any HTML element. Some elements directly
     implement this interface, while others implement it via an interface that inherits it.
     */
    let imageInputNE = imageInputDE.nativeElement ;
    console.log("input element is ",imageInputNE);
    console.log("debug element is ",imageInputDE);
    //imageInputNE.click();
    let fileSelectEvent = new Event("change",{bubbles:true,
    cancelable: false});

    console.log("created event ",fileSelectEvent);
    imageInputNE.dispatchEvent(fileSelectEvent);

    expect(newPracticeQuestionComponent.handleFileSelect).toHaveBeenCalled();


  });
```

The above might not be the best solution as I can't manipuate `files` in the `input` field but this is the best I could come up with!

Answer (score 0):

Coming from the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54242969/146656), I'd suggest you change the `handleFileSelect` to just take `files`.

```
interface File {
  // the properties you need, for example:
  name: string;
}

// You don't need all this unless you must use `item()`
// interface FileList {
//     readonly length: number;
//     item(index: number): File | null;
//     [index: number]: File;
// }
// instead, just use ArrayLike<File>
export function handleFileSelect(files: ArrayLike<File>) {
    // Write code here, for example:
    if (files.length > 0) {
        console.log(files[0].name);
    }
}
```

Then your test should be just:

```
const files = [{
  name: 'File 1'
}];
handleFileSelect(files);
```

And your component will just:

```
handleFileSelect(event.target.files);
```

[Here's an example](https://typescript-play.js.org/?strictNullChecks=false#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGLADYoN4ChnID0hyYAFigA5QD2l0YwEAzsgJ40CuyIEEAJgBpkMGlGQQAHnAC2lLAC58PWRAXJmYKKADmAblwBfXLmLIAml2T8aIAORgeffsjgYMpMsFacQWZqwc3DKcmsihKAAGwJAyABQAlJGmJKCQsIgo6FgAMt6OeGYEBFAQcDZ+bMhYIDrk6iCcMgBG0AZFxTEQ8aD8Ug1NrVAJ6tkoAD48nO7tJMXIANq9-VMt0AC6o5gQs8jGZqCaZULIAFahjhFo2wvruFKUYo4wvgiMtshkcCD8WGMAyhAsG84jBtsx1ABBKBQOBsPIAawgAB4xgA+BLIPAEMwIGh9T7QCBGEx4kBhMFYACSIEonEcAF5rDQEE0IOAAHQ6CBgACiWBk7LAzAAQmwACpwHQAOVUcTsoDpYDsCQWAAZ1gYvj8-ttAcCwKDtjSlRzKSwEgZcGSKeDkEyFtiVIL1HYxsgAIx2Iya3Da34QAFAiAg83MS1AA) that shows how both usages do not trigger an error in the compiler.

Comment: But target.files is of type FileList, not File

Comment: I could try creating another function say extractFile which takes file from FileList and then pass it to handleFileSelct. But I will not be able to test extractFile then

Comment: All you care about for an array is length and number indexer (being able to say `files[0]`). But you are right, using array directly won't work. We can use the buil-tin type `ArrayLike` instead, or of course you can still use the commented `FileList` interace in the answer.

Comment: I updated the answer to use `ArrayLike` and added a link that shows how this does not throw an error in the compiler.

Comment: thanks. I can't seem to find information about `ArrayLike`. Could you please point me to some resource which could help me understand what it is

Comment: Just press F12 on it in VSCode. The declaration is pretty simple. It's an interface that says it has a `length` has number indexer (like `files[0]`). It's as simple as `interface ArrayLike<T> { readonly length: number; readonly [n: number]: T; }`