# unable to create object of type FileList (duck-typing)

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to create an object which follows the following interface

```
interface FileList {
  getter File? item(unsigned long index);
  readonly attribute unsigned long length;
};
```

Eventually, I want to assign that object to the `files` property of `input type=file` `HTML` element

The code I have written so far is

```
let file1 = new File(["foo"],"foo.txt");
    let fl:FileList = {
      item: function(index){
        file1;
      },
      length: 1
    } as FileList;
...
imageInputNE.files = fl ;
```

But I am getting error `TypeError: Failed to set the 'files' property on 'HTMLInputElement': The provided value is not of type 'FileList'.`

I tried creating a `typescript` class as well but that doesn't work either

```
class MyFileList{
  file:File;
  length=1;
  constructor(file:File){
    this.file = file;
  }

  item(index):File|null {
    return this.file;
  }

}

...
let file1 = new File(["foo"],"foo.txt");
    let fl:MyFileList = new MyFileList(file1);
imageInputNE.files = fl ;
```

How could I create an object of type `FileList`?

Comment: What does "ducktaping" mean in the context of the title?

Comment: Sorry. I meant that It seems I cannot create an  object of type FileList. So I suppose I am duck taping here by creating something which looks like FileList

Comment: It's duck-typing

Comment: I will correct that. Thanks

Comment: more information on duck-typing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205130/what-is-duck-typing

Answer (score 0):

You don't have everything that satisfies the standard `FileList`.

If you press F12 on `.files`, you'll go to the standard `lib.dom.d.ts` file, which will show:

```
files: FileList | null;
```

Tracking `FileList` from there will show:

```
interface File extends Blob {
    readonly lastModified: number;
    readonly name: string;
}

declare var File: {
    prototype: File;
    new(fileBits: BlobPart[], fileName: string, options?: FilePropertyBag): File;
};

interface FileList {
    readonly length: number;
    item(index: number): File | null;
    [index: number]: File;
}

declare var FileList: {
    prototype: FileList;
    new(): FileList;
};
```

Not just is it too complex to achieve all above, but also I think the property in reality (ignoring TypeScript for a little bit) is read only.

The property is what the user selected from their own computer. It doesn't make sense security-wise that you'd select files by yourself from their computer.

Of course you can always cast the objects you have to `any` and try yourself to see what happens in runtime.

If the purpose of this that you have some other part of the UI which displays what files are being used, and you want that to show the extra information, I suggest that you modify the part that uses `input.files`, and make it use your other stuff as well, instead of trying to manipulate the property itself.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I am trying to unit test a function which gets called when `change` event is triggered by the `input`. An `Event` object is passed to my function which has `target.files`. As I am unit testing, I don't have the real files so I am trying to make up some data for it

Comment: Could you please suggest how I may do this? This might give you some background but all I can test at the moment is that the function is called but I am unable to test that the function works correctly - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54202209/how-to-trigger-input-onchange-from-angular-spec

Comment: I'd suggest you just change the function to take the `files` array. I answered there.